# Magento - Custom Order Fields - Tutorial Error?

Tags: magento, field

I'm following the tutorial located at:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/how_to_add_custom_field_in_billing_and_shipping_address_in_frontend_and_backend

There's no mention of which version this is for, but it's less than a year old, so I don't see why it shouldn't work on 1.6.2 (the sandbox I'm testing it in - fresh install, nothing done other than change package/theme).

However, after getting this together, the billing address block is failing during checkout (as well as other areas where this should be visible) and the log states:

```
2012-01-31T20:46:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: led to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/order-add-field/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2012-01-31T20:46:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/order-add-field/app/code/local:/var/www/order-add-field/app/code/community:/var/www/order-add-field/app/code/core:/var/www/order-add-field/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/order-add-field/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

So I'm led to believe there is something wrong with how the model is set up. Per the tutorial, config.xml includes (inside global tag):

```
<models>
    <orderfields>
        <class>Ps_Orderfields_Model</class>             
    </orderfields>      
</models>
```

The tutorial doesn't state any models needing to be set up, yet it appears as though something is missing. Do I need the Model file? The mysql install script I assumed would handle this... It feels just a step away, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 1):

The path in the second log message is interesting...

```
Failed opening 'Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/.php' for inclusion
```

IF you take a look in the `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data` folder you'll see a series of files, one for each attribute input type.  This leads me to think that your 'input' array key in the setup script, i.e. the following line...

```
'input'    => 'text',
```

... is invalid or missing for one of your attributes.  Check your setup script, and maybe post the relevant sections here if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused because no class is specified for the setup.

Add the class `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` to the module setup configuration in `config.xml`.

```
<setup>
    <module>Ps_Orderfields</module>
    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
</setup>
```

This will fix the error, but it will not result in a working attribute. Use [this module](https://github.com/iamniels/Magento-custom-address-attribute) to add an attribute to the Magento addresses. The module has been tested with the most recent version of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with same problem (magento 1.7.0.2). After some investigation i fix it by adding this array params to each custom attribute in the installer:

```
 'backend_type'     => 'varchar',
 'frontend_input'   => 'text',
```

instead of 'type' and 'input' in the tutorial.